# context block visibility - disable block for certain role

Tags: 6

I use drupal 6. I want to show a block for all users (anonymous, authenticated, all roles) except role XY and some paths.
I use context module where it is easy to set path rules. However, setting rules does not work - I want to disable block for role XY but enable it for all other authenticated users. So I check all roles I have + authenticated users and leave role XY empty. This way it does not work, probably drupal thinks that all authenticates are all roles. 
What would be the way of achieving this? Thank you.

Comment: An authenticated user is an authenticated user, no matter which role. If your roles are mutually exclusive, just leave that box unchecked and you're done.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps this module might do the job for you https://www.drupal.org/project/hide_block_by_role doing a quick google search suggests that this would be the ideal module for you

Hope that helps

Seamus

Comment: Heh Seamus, you should ask or answer more questions to help grow your reputation so that at 200+ it helps launch the CiviCRM StackExchange site. Cheers, Joe